# How to use rsnapshot without remote root?

Tags: linux, root, rsnapshot

I've configured an in-house server to use rsnapshot to backup our hosted RHEL servers but in order to do so, I'm using the root account on those servers so I have access to everything including restricted /etc files like /etc/shadow.

Is there a better way to do this?

I used this guide: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-rsnapshot-backup-howto/

Comment: I don't know of a backup tool that uses privilege separation, sadly. However, since you care about security, consider a tool that does encrypted back-ups; Duplicity is one.

Comment: I'm not concerned about security of the backups as much as the fact that the root account on our in house server automatically has root access to all of our other servers.

Answer (score 3):

http://marksallee.wordpress.com/2009/10/08/server-backups-with-rsnapshot-rsync-non-root-user/

Comment: So basically the solution is to use `sudo`?